# How to invoke the onclick event on combo box in nsis

Tags: combobox, nsis

I want to apply onClick event on the combo box in nsis installer,so that I can execute a functionality on the click of button on combo box.

Answer (score 1):

The OnClick event is not suitable for a combo-box, you want the OnChange event because the user can change it with the arrow keys etc.

To fire the change event programmatically you can call your handler directly or trick the combobox control:

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh
Page Custom MyPageCreate
Page InstFiles

Function OnComboChange
Pop $0
SendMessage $0 ${CB_GETCURSEL} "" "" $2
System::Call 'USER32::SendMessage(i$0,i${CB_GETLBTEXT},i$2,t.r2)'
MessageBox mb_ok "OnComboChange: $2"
FunctionEnd

Function EmulateChangeMethodA
Pop $0 ; Throw away parameter we don't care about
Push $1
Call OnComboChange
FunctionEnd

Function EmulateChangeMethodB
Pop $0 ; Throw away parameter we don't care about
FindWindow $0 "EDIT" "" $1 
SendMessage $1 ${WM_COMMAND} 0x4000000 $0 ; Send WM_COMMAND,MAKELONG(0,EN_UPDATE),hwndEdit
FunctionEnd

Function EmulateChangeMethodC
Pop $0 ; Throw away parameter we don't care about
!ifndef CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO
!define CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO 0x0164
!endif
System::Call '*(&l4,&i16,&i16,i,i,i,i)i.r2'
SendMessage $1 ${CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO} "" $2 ; This only works on Vista+?
System::Call '*$2(i,&i16,&i16,i,i,i,i.r0)'
System::Free $2
SendMessage $1 ${WM_COMMAND} 0x30000 $0 ; ; Send WM_COMMAND,MAKELONG(0,LBN_SELCANCEL),hwndList
FunctionEnd

Function MyPageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateCombobox} 0 30u 100% 200u ""
Pop $1 ; This is the only control handle we care about in this example so make sure to never overwrite it!
${NSD_CB_AddString} $1 "Foo"
${NSD_CB_AddString} $1 "Bar"
SendMessage $1 ${CB_SETCURSEL} 0 ""
${NSD_OnChange} $1 OnComboChange

${NSD_CreateButton} 0 50u 33% 12u "Emulate change: A"
Pop $0
${NSD_OnClick} $0 EmulateChangeMethodA
${NSD_CreateButton} 33% 50u 33% 12u "Emulate change: B"
Pop $0
${NSD_OnClick} $0 EmulateChangeMethodB
${NSD_CreateButton} 66% 50u 33% 12u "Emulate change: C"
Pop $0
${NSD_OnClick} $0 EmulateChangeMethodC

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.But I want to fire the event on click of the down arrow of the drop down.When the user clicks the down arrow ,the drop down get populated based on the event that gets fired.

Comment: A user can change the combobox without dropping down the list! I don't think nsDialogs supports the dropped-down event anyway. You should rethink your design...